# GSOAP ERROR: SSL verify error or warning with certificate at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, gsoap

I am trying to connect a c++ client code on VC 6.0 windows xp, to a web service and i get this error:

SSL verify error or warning with certificate at depth 1: unable to get local iss
uer certificate

I generated all the autogenerated files of soap and wrote my client code which is as follows.

```
#include <stdsoap2.h>
#include "WSGetRedemptionSellingPriceListV1ServiceSoapBinding.nsmap"
#include "soapWSGetRedemptionSellingPriceListV1ServiceSoapBindingProxy.h"
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sched.h>

int CRYPTO_thread_setup();
void CRYPTO_thread_cleanup();
void sigpipe_handle(int);

int main()
{
    int returnValue=-1;
    struct soap *soapObject = new soap;
    char *userid = new char[strlen("SID488")+1];
    char *password = new char[strlen("lzmyf5hP")+1];
    char *transactionID=new char[strlen("1318855997052")+1];
    ns1__Transaction *Transaction = new ns1__Transaction;
    const char* headerString = "<S:Header> \
    <ns1:Security xmlns:ns1= http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd> \
    <ns1:UsernameToken> \
    <ns1:Username>SID488</ns1:Username>\
    <ns1:Password>lzmyf5hP</ns1:Password> \
    </ns1:UsernameToken>\
    </ns1:Security>\
    </S:Header>";
    char *ip = new char[strlen("163.166.143.21")+1];
    char *header = new char[strlen(headerString)+1];
    const char* endPoint = "https://wsgtwy-uat.baplc.com/webservices/gateway/CAPSellingWSLive/BA_GetRedemptionSellingPriceList";
    const char* soapAction = "http://www.ba.com/schema/esb/tGetRedemptionSellingPriceListV1/WSGetRedemptionSellingPriceListV1PortType/getRedemptionSellingPriceList";
    _ns1__GetRedemptionSellingPriceListRequest requestObject;
    _ns1__GetRedemptionSellingPriceListResponse responseObject;

    strcpy(ip,"163.166.143.21");
    strcpy(header,headerString);

    strcpy(userid,"SID488");
    strcpy(password,"lzmyf5hP");
    soap_ssl_init();

    if (CRYPTO_thread_setup())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot setup thread mutex for OpenSSL\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    soap_init(soapObject);

    soapObject->header = (struct SOAP_ENV__Header *)soap_malloc(soapObject, sizeof(struct SOAP_ENV__Header));
    soapObject->header->authwsns__ip = ip;
    soapObject->header->authwsns__token=userid;


    soapObject->connect_timeout = 60;
    soapObject->send_timeout = soapObject->recv_timeout = 30;



    soapObject->userid=userid;
    soapObject->password=password;
    soapObject->passwd=password;
    soapObject->logfile[0] = "F:\\gSOAP\\gsExample\\recv.log";
    soapObject->logfile[1] = "F:\\gSOAP\\gsExample\\sent.log"; 
    soapObject->logfile[2] = "F:\\gSOAP\\gsExample\\test.log";



    if (soap_ssl_client_context(soapObject,SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT,NULL,NULL,"F:\\gSOAP\\gsExample\\wsgtwy-uat.baplc.com.crt",NULL,NULL))
    {
        soap_print_fault(soapObject, stderr);
        exit(1);
    }



    WSGetRedemptionSellingPriceListV1ServiceSoapBindingProxy serviceInstance;


    requestObject.soap = soapObject;
    strcpy(transactionID,"1318855997052");
    Transaction->TransactionID=transactionID;
    requestObject.Transaction=Transaction;




    returnValue = serviceInstance.getRedemptionSellingPriceList(endPoint,soapAction,&requestObject,&responseObject);
    if (returnValue == SOAP_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "SOAP_OK");
    }
    else
    {
        soap_print_fault(soapObject, stderr);
    }

    CRYPTO_thread_cleanup();
    return 0;
}

/******************************************************************************\
 *
 *  OpenSSL
 *
\******************************************************************************/

#ifdef WITH_OPENSSL

#if defined(WIN32)
# define MUTEX_TYPE     HANDLE
# define MUTEX_SETUP(x)     (x) = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL)
# define MUTEX_CLEANUP(x)   CloseHandle(x)
# define MUTEX_LOCK(x)      WaitForSingleObject((x), INFINITE)
# define MUTEX_UNLOCK(x)    ReleaseMutex(x)
# define THREAD_ID      GetCurrentThreadId()
#elif defined(_POSIX_THREADS) || defined(_SC_THREADS)
# define MUTEX_TYPE     pthread_mutex_t
# define MUTEX_SETUP(x)     pthread_mutex_init(&(x), NULL)
# define MUTEX_CLEANUP(x)   pthread_mutex_destroy(&(x))
# define MUTEX_LOCK(x)      pthread_mutex_lock(&(x))
# define MUTEX_UNLOCK(x)    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(x))
# define THREAD_ID      pthread_self()
#else
# error "You must define mutex operations appropriate for your platform"
# error "See OpenSSL /threads/th-lock.c on how to implement mutex on your platform"
#endif

struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value
{ MUTEX_TYPE mutex;
};

static MUTEX_TYPE *mutex_buf;

static struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value *dyn_create_function(const char *file, int line)
{ struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value *value;
  value = (struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value*)malloc(sizeof(struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value));
  if (value)
    MUTEX_SETUP(value->mutex);
  return value;
}

static void dyn_lock_function(int mode, struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value *l, const char *file, int line)
{ if (mode & CRYPTO_LOCK)
    MUTEX_LOCK(l->mutex);
  else
    MUTEX_UNLOCK(l->mutex);
}

static void dyn_destroy_function(struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value *l, const char *file, int line)
{ MUTEX_CLEANUP(l->mutex);
  free(l);
}

void locking_function(int mode, int n, const char *file, int line)
{ if (mode & CRYPTO_LOCK)
    MUTEX_LOCK(mutex_buf[n]);
  else
    MUTEX_UNLOCK(mutex_buf[n]);
}

unsigned long id_function()
{ return (unsigned long)THREAD_ID;
}

int CRYPTO_thread_setup()
{ int i;
  mutex_buf = (MUTEX_TYPE*)malloc(CRYPTO_num_locks() * sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
  if (!mutex_buf)
    return SOAP_EOM;
  for (i = 0; i < CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++)
    MUTEX_SETUP(mutex_buf[i]);
  CRYPTO_set_id_callback(id_function);
  CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(locking_function);
  CRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback(dyn_create_function);
  CRYPTO_set_dynlock_lock_callback(dyn_lock_function);
  CRYPTO_set_dynlock_destroy_callback(dyn_destroy_function);
  return SOAP_OK;
}

void CRYPTO_thread_cleanup()
{ int i;
  if (!mutex_buf)
    return;
  CRYPTO_set_id_callback(NULL);
  CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(NULL);
  CRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback(NULL);
  CRYPTO_set_dynlock_lock_callback(NULL);
  CRYPTO_set_dynlock_destroy_callback(NULL);
  for (i = 0; i < CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++)
    MUTEX_CLEANUP(mutex_buf[i]);
  free(mutex_buf);
  mutex_buf = NULL;
}

#else

/* OpenSSL not used, e.g. GNUTLS is used */

int CRYPTO_thread_setup()
{ return SOAP_OK;
}

void CRYPTO_thread_cleanup()
{ }

#endif

/******************************************************************************\
 *
 *  SIGPIPE
 *
\******************************************************************************/

void sigpipe_handle(int x) { }
```

A quick reply would be helpful.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30497/Creating-a-gSoap-eBay-Client-Application-with-Visu) to a code project article, I think you need to look at section 5 mostly.